# How do I get the value of a sibling field in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
class A
{
    public B;
    public C;
}
C func()
{
    A a=new A();
    // set the fields in private
    return a.c;
}
```

I only have an object returned by func()

```
C c=func()
```

How do I get the value of the connected field b?

I know I can get the type of b through Type.ReflectedType,but I don't know how to get the value of b.

Comment: Since you don't return the class instance, the two values for `B` and `C` are not connected, and thus not `B` is not accessible through *just* `C`.

Comment: public B b;public C c;

Comment: You should be providing example code *that compiles*; your code doesn't compile for *numerous* reasons.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it clearly . c is a delegate that using b.that means object  a will not be garbage collected

Comment: @海牙客移库 Then *show that in your code*.

Comment: If you have **all** instances of `A` saved somewhere (e.g. `List<A>`), then you can enumerate those to find in which `A` given `C` is and then you have your `B`. But this rather seems a design problem. As a quick fix - save that `new A()` into a field/property and use that after calling `func()` (not thread-safe).

Comment: `public class SomeFunc
{`
    `public void Call()`
    `{`
        `// do something`
    `}`
    `public int a;`
`}`

`public class SomeType`
`{`
    `public SomeFunc func=new SomeFunc();`
     `public void Call()`
    `{`
        `func.Call();`
    `}`
`}`


`Delegate d=new SomeType().Call`
I only know d,I want to know a

Comment: Is there anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it myself.

Use Delegate.Target to get the parent object